# DateTime.ParseExact throwing FormatException when data is valid

Tags: c#, wcf, datetime, automapper

So here is the story - I have had an error that occurred in the WCF Service while mapping Service model to Domain Model. I am using automapper do to the mapping between the two layers. My mapping string is the following:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<WM.CAD.BusinessLayer.Models.Job, JobResponse>()
.ForMember(s => s.DateWanted, 
      m => m.MapFrom(q => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(q.DateWanted) 
      ? DateTime.ParseExact(q.DateWanted, "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
      : default(DateTime?)));
```

It has been working with no issues for a while but all of the sudden I received an error

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException:  Mapping types: String ->
>   Nullable1 System.String -> System.Nullable1[[System.DateTime,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] Destination path:
>   JobResponse.DateWanted.DateWanted Source value: 20150916 --->
>   System.FormatException: 20150916 is not a valid value for DateTime.
>   ---> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

The format is correct yyyyMMdd the source value was 20150916. It is blowing my mind and I cannot figure out why this error happened. As well once the first error occurs all following transactions to the service are broken as well until Application Pool on the server is reset. Once the app pool is reset everything is working even for the transaction that said it was broke.I don't know if it is a bug with DateTime.PraseExact or Automapper any help would be great since I'm loosing my mind with it.

### UPDATE

After more investigation it was found that there was a high memory usage on the server and high CPU usage on the server hour before the issue happened. One other thing was that the application pool restarted it self at exactly the same time the error occurred... Is that coincidental? Could Application pool resetting itself cause these types of errors?

Comment: are there any hidden chars?

Comment: I have verified the database and no hidden chars were present like spaces... The problem is once the first error occurs all following transactions are broken as well until Application Pool on the server is reset.

Comment: Seems like memory corruption.  Are you calling any native DLLs (e.g. interop)?

Comment: That is what I initially thought as well. I looked through all the server logs including IIS logs and also done a stress test on the Service to see if I can duplicate the error and no luck. No, I am not calling any native DLLs. Unless automapper does.

Comment: Not directly related but why isn't `DateWanted` a DateTime value already? Even if the date was stored as a string in the database, SQL Server at least can convert this to `datetime` or `date` unambiguously

Comment: Please check the text values again. Spaces aren't hidden but there may be other, non-printable values. Does `DATALENGTH()` on the column return what you expect (8 for varchar, 16 for nvarchar)?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos its a Oracle database also its a vendor database and they require a data to be in a specific format.

Comment: If the column's data type is DateTime, then it doesn't have a format!  What is the data type of the column in the database?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway the type is varchar(20)

Comment: @NickManojlovic Oracle also has date and time types. You can make the conversion in the select clause, if you don't want to change the type of the field.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes it does - vendor actually has a trigger on that column if the length is greater than 8 to use null

Comment: Try this by adding datetime style DateTime.ParseExact(q.DateWanted, "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None)

Comment: @Chandru the call is correct as is. It should return a valid datetime. In fact, I can't reproduce this and I bet the OP can't reproduce it either outside production

Comment: Well before I make any changes I would like to figure out why it even happened since it has been working for a long time. +

Comment: For testing purpose put foreach to read all the DateWanted property and TryParseExact and you will find which data make you problem.

Comment: @Chandru, the value is displayed in the exception message itself.

Comment: Memory corruption almost by definition isn't about the framework, it's a problem on the machine. If the framework hasn't gone crazy, you may be using local alphabet characters in the format string or the input may contain hidden characters. This doesn't appear to be the case though, assuming you've pasted the exact same code and error. Even in hex view the characters appear correct.

Comment: @NickManojlovic how high is the CPU load when this occurs? Could it be that the server is starting to crash due to sustained high CPU load?

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos. Yea that is an exact paste of an error from AppDynamics that monitors the service. I am leaning towards the memory as well on the server but I don't know the best way to make it happen again :). I did the stress test on the lower environments not under production server.

Comment: Does automapper store any sort of state that would be impacted by the AppPool recycle?  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2006/01/26/thoughts-on-application-pool-recycling-and-application-availability.aspx